# p0401 continues to show after replacing parts on 2002 lincoln blackwood 5.4L

Tags: throttle, egr, lincoln, p0401

P0401 continues to show after replacing egr valve, sensors, cleaned throttle body and still showing P0401 code. What else could be problem, any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked all the stuff listed [shown for the P0401 code](https://www.carparts.com/blog/p0401-code-exhaust-gas-recirculation-egr-flow-insufficient-detected/)? Specifically, look under the section which is headed "P0401 on Some Ford Vehicles". There are 14 different things which some Ford vehicles can have issues with which can trip the code.